# Remove previous arrow of carousel from react bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am using React Bootstrap Carousel, I'm trying to remove the previous arrow of the controls, but I don't know how:

```xml
<Carousel>
    <Carousel.Item>
        <img
        className="d-block w-100"
        src="1.jpeg"
        style={{borderRadius:"15px"}}
        height="500"
        alt="First slide"
        />
        <Carousel.Caption>
            <h3>First slide label</h3>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
        </Carousel.Caption>
    </Carousel.Item>
    <Carousel.Item>
        <img
        className="d-block w-100"
        src="5.jpg"
        style={{borderRadius:"15px"}}
        height="500"
        alt="Third slide"
        />
        <Carousel.Caption>
            <h3>Second slide label</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </Carousel.Caption>
    </Carousel.Item>
    <Carousel.Item>
        <img
        className="d-block w-100"
        src="3.jpg"
        style={{borderRadius:"15px"}}
        height="500"
        alt="Third slide"
        />
        <Carousel.Caption>
            <h3>Third slide label</h3>
            <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
        </Carousel.Caption>
    </Carousel.Item>
</Carousel>
```

I'm new to react-bootstrap please help me with this task of removing the previous arrow.

Answer (score 6):

```
<Carousel controls={false}> // Hide next and previous buttons
 ....
</Carousel>
```

Answer (score 4):

Declare it as:

```js
<Carousel prevIcon={<span aria-hidden="true" className="carousel-control-prev-icon" />} >
...
..
.
</Carousel>
```

From [documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/carousel/).

Answer (score 3):

It's quite easy. Just pass the prop "controls" into Carousel and give it a false value. don't forget the {} when passing in false

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
<Carousel indicators={false}>
 ....
</Carousel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try explicitly overriding the indicator-related props of the `Carousel` component, like this:

```
<Carousel nextIcon="" nextLabel="">
  ...
</Carousel>
```

[Documentation of Carousel's available props here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/carousel/#carousel-props).